# How to improve performance of oracle query in finding referential table name

Tags: oracle

I got query below:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS 
WHERE R_OWNER = 'OWNERNAME' AND STATUS ='ENABLED' AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'R' 
AND R_CONSTRAINT_NAME IN ( SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM ALL_CONSTRAINTS  
WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE IN ('P', 'U') AND TABLE_NAME = 'REGIONS' 
AND OWNER = 'OWNERNAME' )
```

It took 4 Secs to get output  of it.

Is there any better way to get the name of referential table name?

Thanks in advance.

Joon

Comment: why do you use ALL_CONSTRAINTS  table in subquery?

Comment: There is no reason for that. It will be better if I use user_constraints?

Comment: I tested with user_constraints. It took 3 Secs instead. I am trying to find better way of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a join condition missing in your query:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME,
       CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS 
WHERE R_OWNER = 'OWNERNAME'
  AND STATUS ='ENABLED'
  AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'R' 
  AND (R_OWNER, R_CONSTRAINT_NAME) IN ( SELECT OWNER, CONSTRAINT_NAME
                                        FROM ALL_CONSTRAINTS  
                                        WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE IN ('P', 'U')     
                                          AND TABLE_NAME = 'REGIONS' 
                                          AND OWNER = 'OWNERNAME' )
```

You are not limiting R_OWNER to 'OWNERNAME' which means that is has to look at all constraints in the schema OWNERNAME not only those that link to the table OWNERNAME.REGIONS.

Comment: Thanks fhossfel a lot.

Comment: I tried with you code and I got message  ORA-00947: not enough values.

Comment: Sorry, I have fixed it. There was the OWNER column missing in the sub-select.

Comment: Thanks fhossfel.
I am out for vacation now. I will check it ou when I get back to work.

Thanks again
Joon

Comment: Thanks fhossfel.
Iam out for vacation. 
I will try it soonest I get to work.

Thanks again.

Comment: I tested but it doesn't help improving its performance. It took 4 Secs as before. If you have tested with your own db, did you get any difference? Thanks any way.

Comment: Then there is something wrong with you DB. On my machine using the HR Schema for reference the query would take 30 ms. Either your DB is very slow or your schema is HUGE.

Comment: Thanks fhossfel! I will have some one look into my db.